# Predictive Data Logger Device

Tags: arduino

I'm searching for an IOT componenet/device/automaton that logs date/time when it is used(button presses?), and has a simple output(Vdc probably) that turns on automatically over time when machine confidence builds up and monitors itself for correctness. I'm guessing it's more of a software problem/machine learning you can solve with a ESP8266, sensors and a FET transistor that drives a DC relay. I'm asking if an engineered integrated solution exists.

Comment: what does this have to do with IoT?